# how do you load the US Department of Defense Certificate into an iPhone?

Tags: ios, certificate, ssl, configuration-profiles

How do you load the US Department of Defense SSL certificate (or any SSL certificate) into  iOS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you'll need to obtain the SSL certificate, sending it to you via email or grabbing it from a web. Once *opened* (tapping on it from the email attachment, for instance) an installation process will start.

1. On the *Install Profile* screen, tap on **Install**.

   [image: The *Install Profile* screen]
2. A *warning* message saying that *Installing this profile will change settings on your iPhone* will appear. Tap **Install now**.

   [image]
3. If your device is *Pin Protected* you'll be prompted to enter it.
4. You'll, then, be prompted to enter the certificate's password. Tap on the **Next** button on the top right corner of the screen, once the password has been entered.

   [image]
5. The certificate will be installed, and a screen with the new certificate will be show.

   [image]

Comment: Excellent answer, nice screenshots.